# Scroll dx, dy using AccessibilityService in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, accessibilityservice, accessibility

Hi I want to scroll dx or dy using AccessibilityService, currently I am using below code to scroll but this performs 1 full page scroll, how can i scroll based on values like (x1, y1) to (x2, y2) or using dx/dy using performAction() function in AccessibilityService.

```
public boolean scrollView(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo) {

    if (nodeInfo == null) return false;

    if (nodeInfo.isScrollable()) {
        return nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeInfo.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if (scrollView(nodeInfo.getChild(i)) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false; }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: See currently there are 2 actions provided by AccessibilityService which are SCROLL_FORWARD and SCROLL_BACKWARD, but in these actions a full 1 page scrolling is done, I want to scroll based on x1,y1 and x2, y2 values.

Comment: Do you want that behaviour with AccessibilityService only or any workaround would be fine?

Comment: I want to perform this action in background on top of other apps so is there any other work around for that?

Comment: You could theoretically try to find a scrollview / recyclerview in the view hierarchy and then call `smoothScrollBy` / `scrollBy` for example

Comment: I need that action to be performed on other apps, one can't access views of other apps, the best thing one can do find node relating to that view and in node only 2 scrolling methods are provided which i have discussed above.